# Cannot connect to instance after reboot

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

its second time when after reboot instance cannot connect to them via SSH. Before reboot all is working well. Can I use serial console, but not know the user and password.

Comment: This article may help ... https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the guide provided by *@Kolban*. When using serial console keep in mind that:

> The interactive serial console does not support IP-based access
>   restrictions such as IP whitelists. If you enable the interactive
>   serial console on an instance, clients can attempt to connect to that
>   instance from any IP address. Anybody can connect to that instance if
>   they know the correct SSH key, username, project ID, zone, and
>   instance name.

More information you can find in the documentation [Interacting with the Serial Console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console).

There're more ways to troubleshoot SSH connectivity then serial console. Have a look at the [Troubleshooting SSH guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) and [Known issues](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#known_issues) for SSH in browser. In addition, Google provides a [troubleshooting script](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-ssh-diagnostic-sh) for Compute Engine to identify issues with SSH login/accessibility of your Linux based instance.

In some cases, the cause of the connectivity problem could be running out of free space of you disk system. In this case update your question and I'll provide you extra instructions.